# How GAE(python) need to Receive mail and post on Message Board then send mail to all user?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, email

anybody knows what wrong with my program??
I write a main.py. and launch it to GAE.
but when I key some word on GAE,it can't send mail to the authors in the table

```
 
    class Send(webapp.RequestHandler):         
       def send(self):

          mail.send_mail(sender=users.get_current_user(), 
                             to=Greeting.author.all(),#Table 
                           body=self.request.get('content'))

          self.redirect("/")

    application = webapp.WSGIApplication([
      ('/', MainPage),
      ('/sign', Guestbook),##click sign to use Guestbook
      ('/sign', Send)
    ], debug=True)
```

And I write a handle_incoming_email.py
 try to send a mail to 123@http:appid.appspotmail.com
but I can't see any thing in the table and can't send mail to the authors in the table

```
    class ReceiveEmail(InboundMailHandler):
        def receive(self,message):
            logging.info("Received email from %s" % message.sender)
            plaintext = message.bodies(content_type='text/plain')

            mail.send_mail(sender=mail_message.sender, 
                               to=m.Greeting.author.all(), 
                             body=plaintext)

    application = webapp.WSGIApplication([
      ReceiveEmail.mapping()
    ], debug=True)
```

Comment: I recommend reading the Python getting started guide (http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstarted/) which has a demo of a simple guestbook. Then read the mail API overview (http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/mail/).

Answer (score 2):

For recieving email see http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/mail/receivingmail.html

For sending email see http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/mail/sendingmail.html

e.g.

```
import logging, email
from google.appengine.ext import webapp 
from google.appengine.ext.webapp.mail_handlers import InboundMailHandler 
from google.appengine.ext.webapp.util import run_wsgi_app
from google.appengine.api import mail

class LogSenderHandler(InboundMailHandler):
    def receive(self, mail_message):
        # post it to message board
        # assuming Message is a table
        text = "\n".join(mail_message.bodies('text/plain'))
        msg = Message(text=text, sender=mail_message.sender)
        msg.put()

        # email msg to list of users
        mail.send_mail(sender=mail_message.sender, to=[list of user], body=text)
```